# Using MySQL to select data from the last three months

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a table which contains the following columns:

- ID = unique identifier in ascending order
- ProductId = Id of a product
- rate1 to rate5 = number of times that product has recived a 1 star, 2
  star, 3 star, 4 star or 5 star rating
- aveRate = average rating for that product
- lastSubDate = last time a review was submitted for that product

And I'm trying to write an SQL statement which selects the ProductId's which have the highest number of 5 star ratings also with an average rating of 5 and the last review submission was within the last three months.

The table looks like this example:

```
ID  ProductId   rate1   rate2   rate3   rate4   rate5   aveRate     lastSubDate
18  9996637     0   0   0   0   1   5   2011-08-10 12:00:34
26  9996628     1   0   0   0   0   1   2010-05-06 05:45:05
34  9996618     0   0   0   1   0   4   2011-10-09 09:00:45
36  9996614     5   0   0   0   0   1   2011-01-05 09:30:32
48  9996592     5   0   1   0   3   3   2012-11-28 19:00:06
66  9996566     0   0   0   1   3   5   2011-04-06 06:45:34
70  9996562     0   0   0   1   1   5   2011-05-17 18:30:03
```

This is the query I've got so far:

```
SELECT `ProductId`,`rate5`,`aveRate`,`lastSubDate` 
FROM ratings 
WHERE `aveRate` = 5 AND `lastSubDate` > '24 Feb 2013' 
ORDER BY `rate5` DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

This returns the products with the most 5 star reviews which also have an average rating of 5, however it doesn't limit the results to the last three months as I want. How can I amend this statement to also select data from only the last three months?

Comment: The last question was about how to merge data from two tables. This question was answered very well and I now have a new table with all this data. This question is about running a select query on this using this new timestamp.

Comment: Yes, this should not be closed. It's a different question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your date constant is in the wrong format. Try this if you're using a constant date:

```
... AND `lastSubDate` > '20130224'
```

You can also use `20130224` (without the quotes) or `'2013-02-24'` above - see the [MySQL Date and Time Literals documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

Or to calculate "three months ago" just do this:

```
... AND `lastSubDate` > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

Finally, you don't need the backticks here. If you find them distracting you can drop them:

```
... AND lastSubDate > whatever
```

Comment: You really should use '21030224' https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries

Comment: Thanks for this CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH is really useful as it will save me working this out in php.

Comment: Thanks @CadeRoux - yet another MySQL nugget I knew nothing about :) Most of the examples I see around here are in the format I posted above, so I took them as gospel. I'll be happy to switch to the shorter and settings-neutral value.

Comment: @CadeRoux That blog is about SQL-Server. MySQL does not have the same issue with settings and accepts both `'21030224'` and `'2103-02-24'` the same way (AFAIK): **[MySQL Date and time literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html)**

Comment: Thanks @ypercube for clearing that up. I'm new to MySQL after years of Oracle and some SQL Server sprinkled in, so I really need to do a systematic study of some of its finer points rather than picking them up as I go along. In the meantime, pointers like yours and Cade Roux's are gold, so thanks to both of you!

Comment: And to clear one more thing, that article of @AaronBertrand is precious. Many of the points there (especially about `BETWEEN`, `>=`, `<` and range queries) apply 100% to MySQL as well (with proper changing of functions as most of them are not compatible when changing DBMS).

Comment: @ypercube Weird - for some reason I thought this was a SQL Server question.

Comment: @EdGibbs My comment doesn't really apply to MySQL.